# I am facing path issue while uploading files in Firefox browser on Windows OS in logs I am able to see / instead of \

Tags: python, java, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, geckodriver

[Robot log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM5Wz.png)

I am trying to upload a file using Firefox browser but it giving me path error in windows system and same code is working on MAC system

If you see log file the in error instead of '\' forward slash '/'black slash visible and it happing only on windows for Firefox browser.

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: File not found: C:\Users\Suraj\Downloads\automation\automation\resources\PageObject\testData\uploadFiles\fztcdrSupportedFiles/sample_bmp.bmp Stacktrace: RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8 WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:187:5 InvalidArgumentError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:378:5 interaction.uploadFiles@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.sys.mjs:543:13**strong text**
```

InvalidArgumentException: Message: File not found: C:\Users\Suraj\Downloads\automation\automation\resources\PageObject\testData\uploadFiles\fztcdrSupportedFiles**/sample_bmp.bmp**

Comment: Did you notice the reference to a Chrome driver in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Using  *Python* for file upload to send a filename through `send_keys()` you need to pass the absolute filepath as follows:

```
uploadElement.send_keys("C:\Users\Suraj\Downloads\automation\automation\resources\PageObject\testData\uploadFiles\fztcdrSupportedFiles\sample_bmp.bmp");
```

Comment: Thank you , but I am using it in robot automation framework and file path is ${sample_doc}      ${CURDIR}${/}fztcdrSupportedFiles/sample_bmp.bmp

Comment: Also if I put entire path it is difficult to run the same test on different system

Comment: @kahirrao you can use join paths for the same. somthing like: ${path} = join paths ${CURDIR} ${asdf} ${asf.pdf} and then try to upload the file using ${path}. more more clarity go through https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Join%20Paths